# Styling the html buttons with CSS/Css3?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to style the buttons with CSS3. Is there any way to style them?

```
<input name="button" type="button" class="abt2" onClick="html2entities(this.form.data1)" onMouseOver="this.className='abt2 abt2hov'" onMouseOut="this.className='abt2'" value="Convert"> 
      <input onMouseOver="this.className='abt3 abt3hov'" onMouseOut="this.className='abt3'" class="abt3" name="Clear" value="  Clear  " type="reset">
```

Comment: Why couldn't you style them? What have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

don't use abt3 abt3hov.

use abt3:hover

```css
.abt3 { background-color: brown; color:red}
.abt3:hover { color:white; }
```

```html
<input class="abt3" name="Clear" value="  Clear  " type="reset">
```